# laravel form helper with put method

Tags: php, laravel

I have this code for form open :

```
{{ Form::model($user, array(
    'route' => array('user_edit_put'), 
    'method' => 'PUT', 
    'role' => "form", 
    'class'=>'form', 
    'accept-charset' => 'utf-8'  
)) }} 
{{ Form::close() }}
```

but this always produces form with post method only, my question is how to create form with another http method in laravel ? why it's always give post method although I've set 'method' => 'PUT'?

Comment: Usually it creates a hidden input with the name `_method`. Look for that hidden input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look in the form there is a hidden field called `_METHOD` that will have the `PUT` method within it. This is to work around as form submission only supports `GET` and `POST`.

Here http://laravel.com/docs/html it says:

> Note: Since HTML forms only support POST and GET, PUT and DELETE
>   methods will be spoofed by automatically adding a _method hidden field
>   to your form.

Comment: how to do that? im new in this stuff

Comment: @YusufErrFound click the tick underneath the arrows :) Go to http://stackoverflow.com/about and click "Take the tour".